# Jsx returns object and causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am learning React and I have this code snippet that builds a html table (data has 100+ object entries) by returning the necessary JSX.

For context, data is also an array of objects:
`[{},{},{}]`

```
const [trafficData, setTrafficData] = useState();

getTrafficDetails().then(r => {
    setTrafficData(r);
})

<TrafficWidget data={trafficData} />
```

consumed in:

```
const TrafficWidget = ({ data }) => {
  let [trafficStatus, setTrafficStatus] = useState([]);

  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    const mapData = data.map((item) => {
      return (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.totalEmission}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
    setTrafficStatus(mapData);
  }

  return(<tbody>{trafficStatus}</tbody>)
}
```

The problem that I have is that when i interrogate `mapData` array, it shows as `{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "tr", key: "082", ref: null, props: {…}, …}` and then causes a `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Why does it come up as an object when i'm returning jsx and why would this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Can we see more code to get the context? data could be an object where it needs to be an array. You are also defining a const after a condition which is generally frowned upon. And we dont know where you are calling that mapData.

Comment: JSX is [always an object](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects). As for the infinite loop - as long as `data` exists and has positive length (we can't see what it is or how it might change), this will update the state on every render, thereby causing a rerender...

Comment: You shouldn't be using state for that.  state should be for if you need to store and mutate the state of `data`, or something else being given to your components as props.  Just put those results in trafficStatus in your render loop.

Comment: API calls should be inside `useEffect`, not in the main body of your function component.

Comment: @user120242 that did the trick. If you write it up as an answer, i will mark it as the accepted answer, & thank you Robin Zigmond.

Comment: `data` changes, which triggers the first re-render (or on mount).  You then map it to a new array object and setState it.  It detects the new array object as different than the old ones, state is changed, and then a re-render is triggered.  Also because the object is different each time, the embedded trafficStatus is reconciled.

Comment: This is a key point: state `saves` data across renders. But if you don't need to save it, don't. Just render what you want you component to look like from the props. Most "presentation" components shouldn't need hooks. Only components that do other things than just present the data need hooks... (There are exceptions to that, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new array object with `.map` each time, causing the state to change at every render call, forcing it to re-render in a loop.  Re-render triggered by `data` changing should be enough to signal a need for re-render.
State should be used to store and mutate the state of `data` or something else being given to your components as props.  Not for storing your component.
You want to let React do the work of reconciling changes in your components, which is what it does well.

You can just feed your mapped components directly in your render loop.

```
const TrafficWidget = ({ data }) => {
  // NOTE: You actually don't need to check the length here.  Empty arrays are handled like no-op.
  const trafficStatus = 
          data && data.length > 0 && data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.totalEmission}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          });
  return(<tbody>{trafficStatus}</tbody>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { Fragment } = React

const TrafficWidget = ({
  data
}) => (
  <tbody>
    {data.map((item) => (
      <Fragment key={item.id}>
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.totalEmission}</td>
        </tr>
      </Fragment>
    ))}
  </tbody>
)


let data = [
  {
    name: "Henry",
    totalEmission: 500,
    id: "936-DEF12"
  },
  {
    name: "Nick",
    totalEmission: 200,
    id: "843-7266B"
  },
]

ReactDOM.render(<TrafficWidget data={data} />, document.getElementById('main'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main id="main">loading or error...</main>
```